# BubbleSorting Dynamic Strcture

Tags: c, struct, logic

i have successfully created a dynamic array of structures but i cannot seem to sort the structures by course name. My struct deceleration looks like.

```
struct info {
char* student;
char* courseName;
int grade;
};
```

my function for sorting has the following decleration,its type pointer pointer because of the way it was created using dynamic memory allocation

```
void sort(struct info **array,int idx);
```

printing student,courseName, and grade members of the built structure prior to sorting

```
Khai IE 3301 69
Ashley MATH 1426 59
Alisaad CSE 1325 31
August CSE 1325 55
Ethan CSE 1320 92
Emily CSE 1310 26
Ahad IE 3301 32
Duke PHYS 1444 29
Duke MATH 2425 90
Ethan MATH 2425 42
Emily MATH 1426 16
Duke MATH 1426 28
Emily CSE 1325 0
Ravindra PHYS 1444 30
August CSE 1325 87
Ravindra IE 3301 51
Ravindra CSE 1310 55
Emily MATH 2425 1
August PHYS 1443 12
```

so what i am trying to do is bubble sort these entries so at the end of the sort my array of structures can have the following form..being alphabetically and numerically sorted

```
CSE 1310 Emily
CSE 1310 Ravindra
CSE 1320 Ethan
CSE 1325.....
IE 3301.....
```

im not very good with pointers sent to functions so i believe this is where i am messing up. Maybe im not refering to the members of the array of structures like i think im doing and trying to swap entries incorrectly but here is my codeblock to sort the array. i have included string.h at the top,and the function is recieving an array of structures that was built correctly,as i printed it in my main codeblock,but the sorting messes the array all up.

```
void sort(struct info **array,int idx) */idx is the size of the finished structure array*/
{
    int unsorted, i;
    struct info temp;

    do {
        unsorted = 0;
        for(i=0; i < idx - 1;i++)
            if(strcmp(array[i]->courseName,array[i+1]->courseName) > 0)
                {
                    temp = *array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    *array[i+1] = temp;
                    unsorted = 1;
                }
    }
    while(unsorted);
    printf("\n");

    int k = 0;
    for(k = 0; k < idx; k++)
        printf("%s %s \n",array[k]->courseName,array[k]->student);
}
```

my output is

```
IE 3301 Khai 
MATH 1426 Ashley 
MATH 1426 Ashley 
MATH 1426 Ashley 
MATH 1426 Ashley 
MATH 1426 Ashley 
MATH 1426 Ashley 
PHYS 1444 Duke 
PHYS 1444 Duke 
PHYS 1444 Duke 
PHYS 1444 Duke 
PHYS 1444 Duke 
PHYS 1444 Duke 
PHYS 1444 Ravindra 
PHYS 1444 Ravindra 
PHYS 1444 Ravindra 
PHYS 1444 Ravindra 
PHYS 1444 Ravindra 
PHYS 1444 Ravindra
```

Comment: Nicely formatted, well presented question.

Comment: Related (ok, slim but still): You also never reduce your bubble-stop with each iteration. It is somewhat the point of bubblesort. With each pass the "winner" bubbles to the current top slot, the index of which (`idx` in your case) is reduced by one for the next pass. The logic for early exit on no-swap detection is spot on, btw, which made me somewhat surprised you missed the stopping-index reduction with each pass.

Answer (score 1):

You need:           `*array[i] = *array[i+1];`

It works because without * you are passing the address of array[i+1] to array[i], so they end pointing to the same value.

Comment: tried that, got error saying incompatible types from struct info

Comment: @ZachSantiago -- you need to show the code that creates the array.  There seems to be some confusion about whether you have an array of structures, or an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't swap structures; swap *pointers*. Your opening sentence claims you have a "dynamic array of structures", but you don't. You have a dynamic array of *pointers*, each of which point to a structure (dynamic or not, its not really relevant).

The easiest way to remember this is to note that the temporary you're swapping with should be one level of indirection removed from your array. Since your array is `struct info **`, the temporary should be `struct info *`; *not* `struct info`.

I've also taken the liberty to properly adjust your top-index reduction I mentioned in general-comment below your question, which should be done with each pass, as well as fix the improper comment on your function declaration line (should start with `/*`, not `*/`. The resulting code looks something like this:

```
/*idx is the size of the finished structure array*/
void sort(struct info const **array, unsigned int idx)
{
    unsigned int swapped = 1, top = idx, i;
    while (top-- && swapped)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for(i=0; i < top; ++i)
        {
            if (strcmp(array[i]->courseName,array[i+1]->courseName) > 0)
            {
                struct info const *temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /* report finale */
    for(i=0; i < idx; i++)
        printf("%s %s\n", array[i]->courseName,array[i]->student);
}
```

That is classic bubble-sort on a dynamic pointer-array.

Comment: +1 but I think you want to pre-decrement `top` in the `while` statement since the inner loop won't run anyways if top is 1.

Comment: @user3386109 the post-decrement is intentional. I'm aware the inner loop won't run with an input of `1`, but likewise the *outer* loop won't run with an input of `0`, and does not require a separate `if` to detect prior to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to swap the struct values or just the pointers to the structs?

If you want to swap struct values (which is what your code appears to want to do) then you probably want:

```
                temp = *array[i];
                *array[i] = *array[i+1];
                *array[i+1] = temp;
                unsorted = 1;
```

Comment: this worked, would you be kind enough to explain why adding the star points to the struct values? pointers are hard for me,thx

Comment: array is struct info **.  It points to an array of pointers.  Those point to items of type struct info.  Thus array[i] is of type struct info * thus is a pointer to a struct info.  temp is of type struct info, so you dereferece (*array[i]) to get the value of the item pointed to by array[i] and copy that into temp.  You then need to copy the contents of the structs pointed to by array[i] and array[i+1], so you need to dereference.  Depending on how you've created array, it might also be possible to just swap the pointers stored in array, instead of the data pointed to by elements in array.